# Auto filter with more than 2 criteria with wildcards

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code in a Macro:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Sheets("Bill").Select
    Range("A2:AA2").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("T2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AA$111").AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=Array("=*Base ch*", _
    "=*Service*", "=*Supply Ch*", "=*Customer*", "=*Analyst*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

It's not showing any error and when I use only 2 criteria It works perfect.
The issue is when I try more than 2. It doesn't show anything.

I tried the operator `OR` but I think that only works with 2 criteria.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This might be useful [AutoFilter based on an array, more than 3 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737474/autofilter-based-on-an-array-more-than-3-elements/46741261#46741261)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `AutoFilter`, try `Advanced Filter` when dealing with multiple wildcard criteria. All you need is to either have a sheet with those criteria listed along with wildcard or create the criteria sheet programmatically and delete it in the end.

The below code will create a criteria sheet programmatically and list all your criteria in column A starting from Row2 and A1 on criteria sheet will contain the column header from your data sheet.

```
Sub FilterWithMultipleWildcardCriteria()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsCriteria As Worksheet
Dim strCriterai
Dim lr As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set ws = Sheets("Bill")
If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
lr = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

On Error Resume Next
Set wsCriteria = Sheets("Criteria")
wsCriteria.Cells.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

If wsCriteria Is Nothing Then
    Set wsCriteria = Sheets.Add
    wsCriteria.Name = "Criteria"
End If

wsCriteria.Range("A1").Value = ws.Range("T2").Value
strcriteria = Array("*Base ch*", "*Service*", "*Supply Ch*", "*Customer*", "*Analyst*")

wsCriteria.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(strcriteria) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(strcriteria)

ws.Range("A2:AA" & lr).AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, wsCriteria.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

wsCriteria.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```