# Autofilter VBA with Array and Wildcard

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, wildcard

I am using `AutoFilter` in VBA. The code below works fine:

**CASE 1:**

```
    Windows("temp.xlsm").Activate
    Columns("A").Select
    arr = Array("=0AY*", "=0BR*")
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But when I try to add one more code item to **arr**, nothing is filtered:

**CASE 2:**

```
    Windows("temp.xlsm").Activate
    Columns("A").Select
    arr = Array("=0AY*", "=0BR*", "=0BM*"  )
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

What's the problem?

Results:

[image]

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858980/auto-filter-with-more-than-2-criteria-with-wildcards

Comment: AutoFilter can only have two criteria with wildcards.