# Table Autofilter not showing correct results when certain data is entered

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, excel-tables

I have built a spreadsheet for users to enter certain references and a button to then filter these in the table.
The column I am searching has 2 values which I have separated with a pipe `|` eg `805457976|3700013275`. The user should be able to enter the first or second value to get a match.
The search values are put into a 1 dimension array, with data type variant/string. I put an asterix `*` at the start and end of each search value.
I then pass this array into the table

Full code as below

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arRefs As Variant
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(Sheet)
    arRefs = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(wb.Names(RangeName).RefersToRange.Value))
    'Remove blanks from Array and enable fuzzy search
    Dim j As Long, jj As Long: jj = 1
    ReDim Arr2(1 To UBound(arRefs))
    For j = 1 To UBound(arRefs)
        If Not IsEmpty(arRefs(j)) Or Trim(arRefs(j)) <> "" Then 'remove blanks
            Arr2(jj) = "*" & arRefs(j) & "*"
            jj = jj + 1
        End If
    Next j
    
    ReDim Preserve Arr2(1 To jj - 1)
    arRefs = Arr2
    
    'Filter Table
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(tblName)
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=arRefs, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Everything appears to work well, until a value is entered that is not in the table eg.

Filters Correctly

```
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Search 1  | Search 2   | Search 3 | Search 4 | Search 5 |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 805457976 | 1018655341 |          |          |          |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Filters Incorrectly (No results at all are shown)

```
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| Search 1  | Search 2   | Search 3   | Search 4 | Search 5 |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 805457976 | 1018655341 | TestSearch |          |          |
+-----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

How can I have it so that if a search reference is not found, the table still filters the results that are found?

Comment: Please add the code you're using (just proving a single line is not very useful)

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams I have added the full code in case it helps.

Comment: When using widcards in an Autofilter array you're limited to 2 values I think.  Using Advanced Filter instead is one possible work-around. See eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858980/auto-filter-with-more-than-2-criteria-with-wildcards